# iOs View orientation

Tags: iphone, ios

I use in my app MailComposer and if it activated in portrait landscape then it works fine, but if I activate it in landscape mode then I see only gray screen.

P.S.
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation return always YES

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the mail composer in my app and in both orientation it works, just check this method

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have it too... If i start Composer in portrait mode and then change the mode to landscape- it works, however, if I close the Composer in landscape mode then I receive the gray screen again